# Why isn't ArrayList<>.add() working?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm new to Java and I'm currently using Android Studio. I just can't understand why .add isn't working. Subject and Assignments are just custom classes. The issue is that the message "Cannot resolve symbol 'add'" pops up and the whole thing fails. I have imported java.util.ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Subject> mSubjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
Subject cheese = new Subject("Cheese",new Assignment[]{new Assignment("Test 1",1.0f,1.0f,1.0f),new Assignment("Test 2",100f,100f,1.0f)},100f,4.0f);
mSubjects.add(cheese);
```

Comment: Is this snippet inside some method or directly in a class? `mSubjects.add(cheese);` must be in a method

Comment: It is all under: " public class MainActivity extends ListActivity"

Comment: it must be in a method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mSubjects.add(cheese);
```

put this method in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Stupid question. But why must method calls be made in the `onCreate`? Also why would making the `ArrayList static` not do the same thing? (I already know it wouldn't I'm just wondering why)

Comment: Alternatively, if you are creating a simple Java class, put `mSubjects.add(cheese)` within the class constructor.