# Integer Array List Adding Elements

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm having a bit of a problem with an ArrayList I'm trying to use for a clock deep link in Android. I'm just trying to create an ArrayList with the values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].

Here's what I have right now:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> daysList = new ArrayList<>();
    daysList.add(5);
```

The `add` is underlined and says "Cannot resolve symbol: add"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: works for me - what version of JDK are you using?

Comment: Could you write your complete code please with packages and error.

Comment: Do you have your own class named `ArrayList`? Also, **what** *is* a "clock deep link"?

Comment: If there was no error for ArrayList, there shouldn't be one for add().

Comment: where did u put the code..?? is it in `onCreate` method??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117592/why-isnt-arraylist-add-working

Comment: @dass Nope- thank you, moving it fixed my problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not sure if it is the right term for what I am doing but it was on the recommendation of Zombie in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494693/android-clock-app-set-alarm/40617440#40617440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `daysList.add(5);` in `onCreate();` or some other method